# on maven project creation throwing errors mentioned below

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.pom. Error code 501, HTTPS Required

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Attached is the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually quite informative here.

> Error code 501, HTTPS Required

Looks like
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 should be https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Please note the second one is ***https***